# How does this time Regex Work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've just inherited a projected with a lot of client side validation.

In this I have found a regex checker, as expected without a comment in sight. I'll admit regex is definitely one of my failing points. (In Javascript!)

```
var myRegxp = /(([0]*[1-9]{1})|([1]{1}[0-2]{1}))(\/{1})((19[0-9]{2})|([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}))$/;
if (!myRegxp.test(args.Value))
{//do fail stuff here};
```

I'm pretty sure from the rest of the page that it's supposed to be checking for some sort of date format. Would this pass MM/YYYY. From some early testing, it *almost* does it.

If this regex doesn't match MM/YYYY, what would be the best way to do this?

Any advice from the regex masters would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: `[1-9]{1}` is equivalent to `[1-9]`. The latter is preferred (by many) because it clutters the regex less. The same goes for `[0]*` being equivalent to `0*` and `[1]{1}` is just `1`.

Comment: Lastly, the logical OR, `|`, has a very low precedence. In other words, you don't need to wrap `AA` and `BB` inside parenthesis in this case: `((AA)|(BB))CC`. You can simply do: `(AA|BB)CC`. That, and my previous remarks, make your current regex: `(([0]*[1-9]{1})|([1]{1}[0-2]{1}))(\/{1})((19[0-9]{2})|([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}))$` exactly the same as `(0*[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3})$`

Comment: Great note at Bart K. +1

Comment: PPS. I see you "anchored" your regex with the *end-of-the-input* character `$`, which leads me to believe you forgot to "anchor" the *beginning-of-the-input* with: `^`.

Comment: @Bart K - please explain the anchoring? As I said, I inherited the code. I'm making this up as I go along :)

Comment: Anchoring means, it will match some part of the text ('subject'), but the 'matching' part won't be included in the returned 'match'. You can tell there is a 'beginning' of a text or line, but you can't just write `<HEY HERE IS A BEGIN>some text`. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should end with MM/YYYY (where MM is 1-12 and YYYY is 1900-9999)

(matching month)

```
([0]*[1-9]{1})
zero or more occurences of '0', and one occurence of 1-9
Example match: 01
```

OR

```
([1]{1}[0-2]{1})
1 match of '1', 1 match of 0-2
Example match: 10
```

Second part (year), first it literally match '/' with:

```
(\/{1})
```

Then the year:

```
((19[0-9]{2})
One match of '/', 19 and two matches of 0-9 (looks like a year in the range 1900-1999)
Example match: 1900
```

OR

```
([2-9]{1}[0-9]{3})
1 match of 2-9 and thee matches of 0-9 (looks like a year in the range 2000-9999
Example match: 2000
```

A simplified RE:

```
var myRegExp = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})$/;
```

Note: `\d` is a character class for `0-9`. I've removed parentheses used for grouping because these are not used in `myRegExp.test`. <strike>Replaced `[0]*` by `0?` since it should not match `0000001/2010`, but it should match `1/2010`.</strike> Replaced `[0]*` by `0` since it should literally match `01` and not `1`. The `^` and `$` are anchors, causing it to match from begin to end. When leaving these out, this RE would match any text containing MM/YYYY.

Comment: In other words for @Kamal: It checks whether a certain string is MONTH/YEAR notation.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. Trolling through the backend, it is indeed a MM/YYYY validation. But it's allowing values up to 19 for the month. From your explanation it is clear it shouldn't allow this?

Comment: Whoops, I missed out some grouping. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think, correct me if I'm wrong. But should it be ([0][1-9]{1})
for the first bit. So that it only allows 1-9 after a 0. And the other OR will cater for the months starting with 1 and only allow 10, 11, 12?

Comment: If you're using `0[1-9]`, it will only match `01`, and not `1`. It depends on your preference, whether `1/2000` is valid or not. You should replace the `0?` (max. one occurrence of zero) by `0` if you want to invalidate `1/2000`.

Comment: Re: your edit. I don't want to allow 9/2010. I want to force the 0. Will my above comment solve that?

Comment: Thank you Lekensteyn. I really have gotten my head around (this) regex now. And I appreciate the explanations as well as now I can start trying to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree - it is checking dates in the format *MM/yyyy*.

It allows any number of leading zeros on the month. It allows years matching 19`xx` or anything else starting with a digit between `2` and `9` inclusive. This means that it allows anything up to 9999 for the year :)

Comment: This program probably won't survive until 12/9999 :D:D:D Or there will be Y10k problem with this particular program.

Comment: Great answers guys. I'm sure somewhere down my bloodline there'll come a day when a coder will curse his great^x grandfather for not being a forward thinker.